# ¿Puedo restaurar una Virtual Machine de Azure sin necesidad de crear una nueva?

Tags: azure

Actualmente revisando la documentación oficial de Microsoft relativa al servicio de Backup solo he conseguido restaurar pero creando una nueva VM, no logro simplemente restaurar la actual, manteniendo por ejemplo la IP. Si alguien ha realizado este procedimiento agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Las opciones que te permiten al momento de restaurar son:

[image: Azure Restore points]

Y si en vez de restaura la VM restauras a nivel de archivo?